# Why is there a different Questions menu on AskUbuntu main menu SIte

Tags: discussion

I  am providing screen shots as follows:

For [Askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)

[image: AskUbuntu]

And for [AskUbuntu questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions)

[image]

Since, by default **Active** is type of question that is being displayed, and rest all at its L.H.S are its Further Date based categories.

And selecting [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions) gets you to a different menu a Newest and others to their L.H.S.

My question may be stupid though , but it confuses a lot to me ( My Mistake) , it is like this , that rather than having two different pages for questions stating **ACTIVE** or **NEWEST** with their respective sub menus, why can't we have one **PAGE** having Either of them as First Menu title and having other (including both pages) options as sub-menus to it .

I am not asking it as feature , rather it is my (and many users , i guess, apologize for this wrong guessing too) folly to discover the site entirely , but prior to few days back as a beginner to this site I was Unable to Locate the Search Bar Hidden at Top-Right Corner , which i read in a answer was present there.

*P.S: May be a total Stupid Question , please post so , so  i can delete.*

Answer (score 5):

It's a way to get high activity questions to the top of the thread, but for people answering questions to disregard question bumping via edit if they want to do so.

Comment: If a mod or admin edits or tags an old question , it gets added to active list .Even if someone comments on solved and old question or edit any answer ,still it gets added to active list.I am aware that default page is a addition of New questions and New activity based question, so is it random in its behavior in listing them like prioritizing it time based or just posted based .[P.S: Not a big concern at all ,but since (example>>) new Hardwares are erupting day-by-day wise, so does the additions  of question in Newest category,so i just thought more attention should be centralized towards it]